# What are the key differences between $ENV_VAR and `env_var`?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

It's a quite simple asked question I think:
What are the key differences between using environment variables just like
$HOSTNAME and `hostname`. Where is which appropriate, why are there two possibillities to represent them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An environment variable is set once and for all (for a given process; when a process launches another, the child inherits the parent's environment). So accessing `$HOSTNAME` directly reads a value in memory. In contrast, each time you evaluate the command substitution `` `hostname` `` (also spelled `$(hostname)`), this executes the `hostname` command.

In the case of `$HOSTNAME` and `hostname`, in practice, it doesn't make any difference. `$HOSTNAME` is marginally faster. In principle, `$HOSTNAME` can be wrong if you've run `HOSTNAME=some_bogus_value` (whereas `$(hostname)` can be wrong if you put some different `hostname` program on your `$PATH`), and only `hostname` keeps up-to-date if you change your host name.

There's often (but not always) a `HOSTNAME` environment variable because it's often used (e.g. in shell prompts) and almost never changes. There's a `hostname` command (on most systems) to set the value of `HOSTNAME` (`HOSTNAME=$(hostname)`) and to change the host name (`hostname $(cat /etc/hostname)`, typically done early in the boot process).

Comment: Gilles is just too good to be simple!! I just wish those Bronze, Gold, Silver badges, as many as you sport, on my name. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It is appropriate to depend on the commands which fetch the current value than the variables which can get stale over a period of time in the unattended sessions.

```
[centos@abc ~]$ /bin/hostname
abc.dns.com
[centos@abc ~]$ echo $HOSTNAME
abc.dns.com
[centos@abc ~]$ uname -n
abc.dns.com

[centos@abc ~]$ sudo /bin/hostname xyz.dns.coom
[centos@abc ~]$ uname -n
xyz.dns.coom
[centos@abc ~]$ /bin/hostname
xyz.dns.coom
[centos@abc ~]$ echo $HOSTNAME
abc.dns.com
[centos@abc ~]$
```

I think its clear that `$HOSTNAME` is a shell variable, which is expanded/evaluated by capturing the output of `/bin/hostname` at the start of the shell initialization and its not updated everytime or if the hostname is dynamic. Depending on the output of `/bin/hostname` is more reliable than $HOSTNAME unless it is the same script or program that has already evaluated the name of the host in the same program space.

Well, in short, output of the commands `/bin/hostname` or `/bin/uname -m` is more appropriate method to know the hostname than just using $HOSTNAME (which could become stale as any other normal SHELL variable).

If you are curious to know how does shell gets $HOSTNAME inherited, then its proper to know that shell reads its global initialization (rc) files like /etc/profile (or /etc/bashrc) which has this variable defined from again output of `/bin/hostname` .

(It is also important to know that programs other than shell without prior executing `/bin/hostname` command can have  HOSTNAME variable defined/initialized  because of the system startup script called `/etc/rc.sysinit` )

Comment: Good explanation. Can you include a comparision of `hostname` to $HOSTNAME and the use of an absolute path?